# Changed Service to Console app, but still no window in 'Release' version - C# - VS2013 Pro

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

**Situation:**

I turned a Windows Service application (C#) into a Console application.

- The service was built to be [self-installing and managing](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/01/c-toolbox-debug-able-self-installable-windows-service-template-redux.aspx) (if that matters)
- All service-related code has been removed.
- The application type has been changed in the properties (I'm using VS2013 Pro).
- All references to service libraries have been removed. 
  I've parsed the entire directory looking for any reference to services and turned up nothing.
- The service has been fully removed

**Problem:**

When compiled to 'Release' no console window shows.

- Shows console just fine when compiled to 'Debug'
- It doesn't show in the Services menu, so I know it's not still running as one.
- It ***does*** show in the process list
- The debugger works just fine
- Occurs on multiple machines (every one I've tried. So far Windows 10, 8 and 7)

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can you give sample code? Maybe the main function and the class for the project?

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't help you much. It's a big app. The `Main` just starts up threads. I'm afraid adding too much would just be a "wall of code" as I don't really know where the issue is occurring.